# close popup in CRM Dynamics with RobotFramework

Tags: selenium, robotframework, robotframework-ide

This one is bothering me for a few hours now.

I'm trying to close the welcome screen popup in CRM Dynamics, however i cant seem to get a good locator match for RobotFramework (in Eclipse). 
The source code of the particular button and surrounding is attached in the screenshot for you reference.

I tried the following locator strategies for the close button (which is an image):

Click Element  `xpath=//img[@alt='Sluiten']`

Click Element  `xpath=//img[contains(@alt,'Sluiten')]`

Click Element  `xpath=//div[@class='navTourButtonImage']`

Click Element  `xpath=//*[@id="navTourCloseButtonImage"]/img`

I also implemented plenty of sleep time after the page is loaded, but this didn't impact anything. any suggestions ?

Looks like the controls are in some kind of iframe as seen below:

Answer (score 1):

I got it sovled by selecting the frame:

```
Select Frame   InlineDialog_Iframe
Click Element    xpath=//img[@alt='Sluiten']
```